# Beagle Bone Black board not able to read or write to GPIO pins

Tags: arm, beagleboneblack

I am using beagle bone black board with AM335X Processor from TI and have a JTAG adapter and use OpenOCD and ARM GDB to connect and read and write to memory. I am trying to read registers of GPIO 1 to set a register with value to see a LED glow. I tried to read certain registers from GPIO 1 and found that all the values are 0 and when I write to the DATAOUT register it says "Cannot write to register"

Any suggestion on this is apprecitated!

Thanks.
Venkat

Comment: no code, no info, no help.  what have you tried what debug did you do, what reading did you do?  what state is the processor in when you took it over via jtag?  did you enable clocks to the gpio block, did you enable the pin as an output.  what does the schematic show as to what level you need to light the led, source the led or sink it to turn it on?

Comment: There is no code which I run. I am trying to access certain registers of the GPIO block and set some registers to get some GPIO high. The processor was halted when I took control over through OpenOCD and GDB. I tried to read the GPIO_OE register which  according to spec has to reset to 0xFFFFFFFF but I was able to read 0x00000000 which seems wrong here. I also tried to write to the DATAOUT register and the GDB/OpenOCD reported it cannot write to that location. With respect to the clock part, I am don't know how to find that.  Sorry for not clearly mentioning it.

Comment: what state it was when you took over matters as to whether this is easy or hard or you have to run code to put it i a usable state.  before you can output enable the gpio you may have to enable clocks to that gpio block and/or other blocks.  have you read up on all of these things and confirmed they are in the right state, ouptut enable and pin state are the last things in sometimes several steps.   running code vs poking over jtag may be required to unlock the chip.  you may have stopped it with the mmu enabled, etc etc etc...what debug have you done?

Comment: if you are running u-boot for example you can halt uboot before it launches linux (uart) and there are many things that u-boot has touched, but in general the chip is not in a state that you might find it if already running linux.  post-reset you have the most control but at the same time the most work.  post u-boot you can have lots of fun but the system has had a bunch of initialization, post kernel start lots of protections, etc are in place

Comment: Thank you for the information on these. I am new to embedded and debugging. I have initially loaded a program using CCS before taking control over using OpenOCD and GDB. and the current state when I connect the GDB is that MMU is disabled, I-Cache and D-Cache is disabled and the processor is in halted state. I have also tried to check if I can get some values in running state, but unfortunately the MMU said that the target has to be halted for that.

Comment: I am not sure about the unlocking of the chip and things as TRM is not clear on that, if you could point me to some resources with these, it would be really helpful. Again, it took me sometime to gather information

Comment: Also, to give more information, I was able to access the SRAM and SDRAM in the processor and modify the contents with GDB but couldn't do anything for peripherals (I think due to halt state causing no clock, gated clock - I am not sure about this) [the code loaded using CCS is a dummy code with print)